# Make drop-down list permanent

Tags: excel, vba

I am an intern with limited VBA experience so please excuse any naivety.

There are two drop down list options (SHOWN IN THE ATTACHED LINK), the drop down list for state is permanently displayed regardless of the cell selected and is formatted in a way that makes it clear that their are options while the country drop down only appears when the cell itself is selected and an objective user would not know there is a list/choice. How do I replicate the state cell for the country cell. Is there a way to find what vba code was used for the state cell?

DROP-DOWN LIST IMAGE
[image: DROP-DOWN LIST IMAGE]

Comment: The state drop-down looks like an ActiveX control that is "floating" on top of the worksheet. The country drop-down is likely driven by the data validation system.

Comment: Do you know how to show the "Developer" tab to be able to interact with ActiveX objects?

Comment: Or you could just hit ALT-F11 to show the VB editor...in there you will find any VBA code associated with the drop-down. On that note, there might not be any code associated with the object...could just be a standard form control with the list built right into it.